# How to Create Table from Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create table from stored procedure, but while executing the procedure, I am getting these errors:

> Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unknown object type 'TABLEPunith_INC_T_Partner_PlusEligible_YE_APJC' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
>   Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object "PTEST" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PTEST2]
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @OBJECTNM    NVARCHAR(100)
   DECLARE @SQLSTR      NVARCHAR(MAX) 

   SET @OBJECTNM =  'PTEST'

   IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'PTEST'))
   BEGIN
        SET @SQLSTR = 'DROP TABLE ' + @OBJECTNM
        EXEC(@SQLSTR)
   END

   SET @SQLSTR = 'CREATE TABLE'  + @OBJECTNM + '(
    Country             VARCHAR(255),
    BE_Geo_ID               INT,
    BE_Geo_Name         VARCHAR(255),
    Certification           VARCHAR(200),   
    )'

   EXEC(@SQLSTR)

   SET @SQLSTR = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @OBJECTNM
   EXEC(@SQLSTR)

   SET @SQLSTR = 'BULK INSERT ' + @OBJECTNM +
                 ' FROM ''C:\Desktop\Part plus.csv''
                   WITH (
                       FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                       ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                       FIRSTROW = 2
                  )'

   EXEC(@SQLSTR)
End
```

I spent hours on this but I am unable execute the stored procedure, also when I tried with different type procedure is executed but table is not created.

Somebody please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks marc_s for suggestion, i have updated SP name and tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @SQLSTR = 'CREATE TABLE_'  + @OBJECTNM + '(
    Country             VARCHAR(255),
```

Missing a space, add it where I put a _ above.
`@SQLSTR` was reading `CREATE TABLEPTEST(` instead of `CREATE TABLE PTEST(`

EDIT, the comment isn't clear, replace your line with the line below exactly. The above did not work because I used an underscore as a placeholder so that you could see where the missing space was.

```
SET @SQLSTR = 'CREATE TABLE '  + @OBJECTNM + '(
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, I have edited like above but still i get the same error, so i edited like `SET @SQLSTR = 'CREATE' + 'TABLE'  + @OBJECTNM + '(..)'`, but now I am getting error like `Incorrect syntax near 'Country'.` i have updated question please have a look.

Comment: you now have no spaces at all.  it evaluates to `CREATETABLEPTEST(`

the line needs to be
`SET @SQLSTR = 'CREATE TABLE '  + @OBJECTNM + '(`